# How can I read a text file in which items are quotations using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file containing long texts, each in double quotation marks, like the following:

```
"blah1 balah1 ..... "
"blah2 blah2 ......."
"blah3 blah3 ......."
"...."
```

I would like to make a `dataFrame` with one column ('text') out of these items. I tried:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_path+'/test.csv')
data.head(10)
```

The output is similar to:

```
blah1 blah1....
0 blah2 blah2
1 blah3 blah3
....
```

It seems except the first row, it can retrive the other rows. How can I have the first row like others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `names` for specify column, then `header=None` is not necessary:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u'''"blah1 balah1"
"blah2 blah2"
"blah3 blah3"'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=['text1'])
print (df)
          text1
0  blah1 balah1
1   blah2 blah2
2   blah3 blah3
```